# Hosting a web site in IIS accessible from any web client?

Tags: iis, hosting, hosts

Trying to host a web site on my local Win 10 Pro machine withing IIS, provided I share the IP to my friends. My host file contains something like:

```
127.0.0.1      site1.com
127.0.0.2      site2.com
127.0.0.3      site3.com
127.0.0.1:1    site4.com 
127.0.0.1:2    site4.com 
123.45.5.6     site5.com  
123.45.5.6:33  site5.com
```

They all work as expected except for the imaginary external ip (only for example), and adding the port or not makes not difference.  Seems i've tried what makes sense, say my external is '1.2" Creating a host entry like
1.2       # or
1.2:Port  # the external IP with port

Also attempted adding an exclusion for he firewall to help ensure the traffic is allowed by doing:

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=81

Kind of lost what might be missing, any suggestions?

Thanks for he help.

Answer (score 0):

First. There is no need to add port after IP address in hosts file. Port can be configured on IIS by setting binding.

Second. If you want to allow any web client can access the site host on local WIN10 pro, you need to make sure WIN10 pro and web client are in the same LAN. Otherwise it is need to buy a public domain and bind to WIN10 pro device.

Using Ping command is a great way to test traffic between devices. It can help you make sure if web client can create connection with WIN10 pro.

Comment: Thanks for the comment,  i'm confused about comment about being on the same LAN,  totally understand needing  a HOST record in the global DNS name servers if I wanted a "FriendlyName.Com", won't the DNS servers only translate "FriendlyName.Com" to 1.2.3.4 and thus resolving to my IIS/Website....  

I was thinking in my goofy host file example that if my external IP:

123.45.5.6:33    site5.com 

Wouldn't the 123.45.5.6 IP be the external/web facing and the site5.com be the site name within my IIS?   Thought i can host any number of sites provided my IIS site is mapped correctly...?

Comment: I cannot understand your puzzle clearly. But on the same LAN, client need to add "server IP friendlyName.com" in hosts and server also need to add "127.0.0.1 friendlyName.com" in hosts file.

Comment: Thanks for trying, i knew i was forgetting something, and yes my forehead is a bit flatter ;)  I set up the host file, setup IIS, opened up my firewall on my machine.... AH, stupid me forgot my router/modem,  didn't punch or port forward 80.  So now i have my IIS web site accessible to all on the web...